# Image background is cut in Java Freemarker pdf template

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I have a pdf template made with Java Freemarker and I want to embed an image in base64 encoding like this:

`"img src="data:image/png;base64," + imgDataAsBase64"`

Users can upload an image that will be put in the template and some images are incorrectly displayed. This image for example:

[image]

is displayed like this in the template:

[image]

I've tried following CSS properties:

`color-adjust: exact !important; print-color-adjust: exact !important;`

But these do nothing.

When same image is put inside standard html file it is displayed correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: FreeMarker is not relevant for your issue.

Comment: I think it is, when I put an image in standard html file it's displayed correctly, I edited the question.